# (How) can I create an email template which digests multiple instances of an SObject?

Tags: email-template, list, singleemailmessage, send-email, collection

Let's say I have a custom SObject `MyObject__c` with a custom text field `Message__c`.

Periodically, I want to send out an email which will collect all instances of `MyObject__c` which have the same value for `MyObject__c.OwnerId` and then send a single email to each Owner which includes (e.g. in a bullet list) all the values for `MyObject__c.Id` and `MyObject__c.Message__c`.

Assuming they are already collected into an instance of `Map<Id, List<MyObject__c>>` How can I do this from Apex, is it possible to send each collection of `MyObject__c` into an instance of an EmailTemplate?

How would I be able to do this?

How would I digest this within the Email Template?

Comment: Have you considered a Visualforce template with custom controller?  If that doesn't work, then you'll probably have to look at document/email merge tools like Conga.

Comment: @DavidCheng, I was hoping there would be a solution more modern and not requiring anything from a third party.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet to achieve this would be [visualforce email templates with custom controller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm). In custom controller you will collect list of SObjects you need and in the template then you can iterate those and display them as you wish.

Comment: It's 2021 and the best bet is rooted in VisualForce?  :-(

Comment: Visualforce is still supported by sf, but maybe there is other way?